# git reset --hard HEAD vs git checkout <file>

Tags: python, git

I have a file `foo.py`. I have made some changes to the working directory, but **not** **staged** **or commited** any changes yet. I know i can use `git checkout foo.py` to get rid of these changes. I also read about using `git reset --hard HEAD`which essentially resets your working directory, staging area and commit history to match the latest commit.

Is there any reason to prefer using one over the other in my case, where my changes are still in working directory?

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any reason to prefer using one over the other **in my case**, where my changes are still in working directory?

No, since they will accomplish the same thing.

> Is there any reason to prefer using [`git checkout -- path/to/file`] over [`git reset --hard`] in [general but not in my specific case]?

Yes: this will affect only the one file.  If your habit is `git reset --hard` to undo changes to one file, and you have work-tree and/or staged changes to *other* files too, and you `git reset --hard`, you may be out of luck getting those changes back without reconstructing them by hand.

Note that there is a third construct: `git checkout HEAD path/to/file`.  The difference between this and the one without `HEAD` (with `--` instead<sup>1</sup>) is that the one *with* `HEAD` means *copy the version of the file that is in a permanent, unchangeable commit into the index / staging-area first, and then into the work-tree*.  The one with `--` means  *copy the version of the file that is in the index / staging-area into the work-tree.*

---

<sup>1</sup>The reason to use `--` is to make sure Git never confuses a file name with anything else, like a branch name.  For instance, suppose you name a file `master`, just to be obstinate.  What, then, does `git checkout master` mean?  Is it supposed to check out branch `master`, or extract file `master`?  The `--` in `git checkout -- master` makes it clear to Git—and to humans—that this means "extract file `master`".

---

#### Summary, or, things to keep in mind

There are, at all times, three active copies of each file:

- one in `HEAD`;
- one in the index / staging-area;
- one in the work-tree.

The `git status` command looks at all three, comparing `HEAD`-vs-index first—this gives Git the list of "changes to be committed"—and then index-vs-work-tree second.  The second one gives Git the list of "changes not staged for commit".

The `git add` command copies from the work-tree, into the index.

The `git checkout` command copies either from `HEAD` to the index and then the work-tree, or just from the index to the work-tree.  So it's a bit complicated, with multiple modes of operation:

- `git checkout -- path/to/file`: copies from index to work-tree.  What's in `HEAD` does not matter here.  The `--` is usually optional, unless the file name looks like a branch name (e.g., a file named `master`) or an option (e.g., a file named `-f`).
- `git checkout HEAD -- path/to/file`: copies from `HEAD` commit, to index, then to work-tree.  What's in `HEAD` overwrites what's in the index, which then overwrites what's in the work-tree.  The `--` is usually optional, unless the file name looks like an option (e.g., `-f`).

  It's wise to use the `--` always, just as a good habit.

The `git reset` command is complicated (it has many modes of operation).

(This is not to say that `git checkout` is simple: it, too, has many modes of operation, probably too many.  But I think `git reset` is at least a little bit worse.)

Comment: Not complaining, but in hindsight my answer reads like a tl;dr of yours... Doesn't help that I posted it earlier ;-)

Comment: @NichtJens: I didn't see yours when I posted mine :-) (possible reason/excuse: my browser was behaving badly and needed restarting)

Comment: This answer could be reworded to clarify that `git checkout HEAD path/to/file` is different from `git checkout path/to/file`. With HEAD, it checks out from a branch, without HEAD, it "checks out" from the index. I was confused because three things changed: -- was removed, "/" was inserted into the path, and HEAD was added. I had to search other sites before I realized what I had missed.

Comment: "copies from `HEAD` commit, to index, then to work-tree". Can I imagine "copied to index" as adding the file to the staging area (==index) after it was reset to the version of the last commit? Since `git add` doesn't do anything if work-tree version equals last-commit version, why is it important to state this step?

Comment: @johk95: the index contains (mode,name,hash) tuples, so "copied to the index" just means finding the right slot in the index and updating the hash part of the 3-tuple. The reason to state this step is that the index *always* contains *every* file that will go into the next commit. During conflicted merge resolution, the index will contain up to 3 entries per file, and the copying-into-index erases all nonzero stage entries, replacing them with a single stage-zero entry, which marks the conflict as resolved. A `git checkout <commit> -- <path>` operation does this. There is a new command [cont]

Comment: [continued] Since Git 2.23, there is a new command, `git restore`, that can copy files from a commit or the index to your work-tree, and can bypass this write-through-the-index mode when copying from a commit. This can avoid the "resolve an in-progress conflict" side effect, should you wish to avoid it.

Comment: @johk95: It might also be worth noting that `git add` will resolve a conflict as well, through the same process: it writes to the index. The case where work-tree and last-commit version all match, the "write to the index" either *just* collapses the three nonzero stage entries into a single stage-zero entry, or else just writes the original hash ID back (which leaves the index entry unchanged and, if no other index entry is changed, means Git doesn't even have to bother writing the index data back).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this can help :

[image: git data transport commands git reset --hard]

Source :
https://www.patrickzahnd.ch

Answer (score 0):

Under your constraints, there's no difference. If there ARE staged changes, there is, though:

`reset` reverts staged changes.

`checkout` does not ...